# Why create Experiment button is disabled in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-ab-testing

I am trying to create an experiment in firebase but button is disabled.
[image]

Can anyone please help in this?

Answer (score 0):

As [per doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Engage%20section%20of,you%20want%20to%20experiment%20with).

You are allowed up to 300 experiments per project, which could consist of up to 24 running experiments, with the rest as draft or completed.

So in my case total experiments were more than 300(**Running:9 , Draft:13, Completed: 291**). I deleted some of the experiment which were not required and i was able to create new experiment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need a higher user permission, same happened to me.